# Open database of filename extensions

Tags: data-request, data-format, software

Filename extensions like ".doc" or ".licx" are usually associated with a type of file, and are sometimes strongly associated with one or several pieces of software.

Is there an open database of these?

- Extension
- Associated file format(s)

  - Description
  - Optionally, what applications are often associated with it

Comment: I think the tables at Wikipedia are the most complete option: Ext.|Description|Used by. For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_list_of_filename_extensions_%28F%E2%80%93L%29

Comment: @philshem: A large part of these Wikipedia tables have been written by me :-)

Answer (score 3):

In today's modern world we think less about the file extensions (suffix) and classify files by their 'Media Type' (formerly MIME type). IANA is the official repository for registering media types. The most complete list ( as of March 5, 2015) is here:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

[This third-party page](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list) which lists MIME types with their typical extensions and has links to more information for each one. If there are media types not listed on that page, you can visit the links in the "template" column from the IANA registration page and find file extension information.

Comment: I am very much aware of that file extensions should be a thing of the past, but unfortunately they are still prevalent, and in this particular question is about them. The page linked in the second paragraph is copyrighted and not licensed unfortunately.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - If you are referring to FreeFormatter.com the author says his tools are free: I created this website to help developers by providing them with free online tools. These tools include several formatters, validators, code minifiers, string escapers, encoders and decoders, message digesters, web resources and more. The author has another website where the content is copyrighted - freegenerator.com

Comment: Independently from the tools available at the same website, what is the license for the file extensions data available at http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list ?